# problems related to the coefficients of holomorphic maps

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F=(f_1,f_2): \bigtriangleup \mapsto \mathbb{C}^2 $ be a  holomorphic maps,  where $ \bigtriangleup \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is  the   complex unit disk. Then each $ f_j (1\leq j \leq 2)$ has a   power series expansion centered at the origin of the  unitdisk
$$ f_j=\sum_{n=0}a_{j,n}z^n,  $$
in which $a_{j,n} \in \mathbb{C}$. If $F(\bigtriangleup )$ is contained in a single complex line of $\mathbb{C}^2$,  what condition would  the coefficients $a_{j,n}$ satisfy? Any hlep would be appreciated.

Comment: By $a_j^n$ do you mean $a_{j,n}$ or $(a_j)^n$?

Comment: It means $a_{j, n}$。

Comment: a point $(w_1,w_2)$ is on a fixed line iff there are $a,b$ not both zero, $aw_1+bw_2=c$; this gives the required relation between the coefficients since $af_1+bf_2=c$ iff the coefficients satisfy the corresponding relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the image of $F$ lies in a single complex line means there are complex constants $c_1,c_2$ and $d$ such that
$$c_1f_1(z)+c_2f_2(z)+d=0$$
for all $z\in\Delta$, equivalently
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}(c_1a_{1,n}+c_2a_{2,n})z^n=-d\,.$$
Since the right-hand side is a constant, and the left is holomorphic, that forces the identities
$$c_1a_{1,0}+c_2a_{2,0}=-d$$
$$c_1a_{1,n}+c_2a_{2,n}=0\,,~\,~\,~\,~\forall n\ge 1\,.$$